# How to match a filename pattern in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

How can i match a filename, which is exactly (Capitals included) in the following format/pattern:
**yymmdd_Name1_Data_Prices**,
**yymmdd_Name1_Data_Contact**,
**yymmdd_Name1_Data_Address**.

I have files that need to be uploaded and the filenames are saved in a database. I want to match the given filename, with the pattern from the database, but i am unsure how to do that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to make that clear. In general, it's best to edit questions rather than clarifying in comments. Questions should be self-contained, in part because not all readers read all comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression.

```
\b\d{6}(?:_[A-Z][a-z]+){3}\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dKDoD2/1/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\b              # match word break
\d{6}           # match 6 digits
(?:             # begin non-capture group
  _[A-Z][a-z]+  # match '_', one upper-case letter, 1+ lower-case letters  
)               # end non-capture group
{3}             # execute non-capture group 3 times
\b              # match word break
```

Match the first 6 characters, which corresponds to a date, could be more precise than simply matching 6 digits. For example, assuming the year is `2000-2020`, one could replace `\d{6}` with

```
(?:[01]\d|20)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|30|31)
```

but it still does would not ensure the date is valid.